# tar on Windows does not handle paths with special characters

Tags: windows, shell, tar, non-ascii, latin1

On a Windows 10 command line, creating a `tar` archive with "special" characters (e.g. extended latin) in the path of the archive itself results in errors.

To be slightly more exact, a quick sample suggests that characters above unicode code point 255 seem to fail. That is [Latin Extended-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Latin_Extended-A) and above.

*Note: This is about the* ***path of the tar archive itself***. *The files inside the archive (a.k.a. members) all have "simple" ASCII paths.*

*Note: out-of-the-box Windows 10 [includes bsdtar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows) from [libarchive](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive), located in `c:\Windows\System32\tar.exe`.*

For example, `tar -c -f Ā.tar foo` creates an archive called `A.tar`, instead of `Ā.tar`.

Similarly, if I have an existing archive called `Ā.tar`, then `tar -t -f  Ā.tar` yields

> tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'A.tar'

and something like `tar -c -f Δ.tar foo` fails altogether with

> tar: Failed to open '?.tar'

Question: ***What could be the cause, and is there a fix or workaround?***

Some observations:

- the issue was reproduced in *cmd*, *powershell*, and (git-)*bash* (explicitly calling `c:\Windows\System32\tar.exe` in bash)
- the issue does *not* arise with GNU tar, as bundled with git-for-windows (also tested in cmd, powershell, and bash)
- the issue does *not* arise on Ubuntu Linux (calling `bsdtar` after installing `libarchive-tools`)
- similar problems arise if the `tar` *members* have characters above code point 255 in their path, even if using the PAX format (this does appear to extend to GNU tar as well)
- default codepage is [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), but changing codepage, e.g. `chcp 65001`, makes no difference
- moreover, not all characters from codepage 437 seem to work either
- other programs work just fine with the same "special" characters, e.g. `notepad Δ.txt`

Personally I always stick to ASCII paths, but this issue becomes relevant if, for example, people use special characters in their Windows username. These will end up in `%USERPROFILE%`.

Possibly related:

- libarchive [#587](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/587), [#1629](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1629), ...
- [Can the UTF-8 code page identifier (65001) be different on other computers?](https://superuser.com/q/1118106)
- ...

Answer (score 1):

This problem was evoked in the bug-report
[Paths with unicode characters in them? #6](https://github.com/haskell/tar/issues/6).

The bug-report itself dates from 2015, but only on Dec 22, 2023,
Bodigrim announced:

> Unicode filenames should work now, after [aa683b0](https://github.com/haskell/tar/commit/aa683b018e1ce31a1c018a7a887ea2504a261169). I switched TarPath to PosixString; since it's not exposed, this is not a breaking change.

The Windows `tar.exe` dates from November 2023, so cannot yet include
this fix, and it's unknown when it will find its way to Windows.

I advise to avoid using the Windows version for the near future,
or alternatively to avoid using paths with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. *"... avoid using paths with non-ASCII characters."* That's the best advice imho. Unfortunately, if people set their Windows username with non-latin characters, these end up in the `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: The other advice would be to use an alternative product.

Comment: As in "Linux"? ;-) Or GNU tar? Or not tar at all?

Comment: As in 7Zip under Windows, but it's not the only one.

Comment: For those that have git-for-windows, they could also use GNU tar, e.g. `...\Git\usr\bin\tar.exe`. GNU tar does not have the specific problem described in the question, although it does also fail on *member* paths with "special" characters.